# Getting `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` while executing SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

When I am trying to execute below SQL query on Oracle 19c DB I am getting error

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Code:

```
alter system flush buffer_cache;
```

Do I need to grant some privileges to user / schema?
As per my understanding I need to grant alter privilege on user/ schema, but I am getting which table has to be granted alter privilege?

Comment: _Do I need to grant some privileges to user/ schema?_ Signs say Yes.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but `alter system` sounds like it  would need general administrative privileges.  I don't think this is related to a specific table.  (Unless `system` is actually a table in the user schema...)

Comment: This is for DBAs, not for users.

Comment: ***insufficient** privileges* - obviously, you have to grant something. But you should not do this operation by a regular user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to grant some privileges to user / schema?

From the [`ALTER SYSTEM` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-SYSTEM.html#GUID-2C638517-D73A-41CA-9D8E-A62D1A0B7ADB):

> ### `ALTER SYSTEM`
>
> #### Purpose
>
> Use the `ALTER SYSTEM` statement to dynamically alter your Oracle Database instance. The settings stay in effect as long as the database is mounted.
>
> When you use the `ALTER SYSTEM` statement in a multitenant container database (CDB), you can specify some clauses to alter the CDB as a whole and other clauses to alter a specific pluggable database (PDB).
>
> See Also:
>
> - [Oracle Database Administrator's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf&id=ADMIN13652) for complete information on using the `ALTER SYSTEM` statement in a CDB
>
> #### Prerequisites
>
> To specify the `RELOCATE CLIENT` clause, you must be authenticated `AS SYSASM`.
>
> To specify all other clauses, you must have the `ALTER SYSTEM` system privilege.
>
> If you are connected to a CDB:
>
> - To alter the CDB as a whole, the current container must be the root and you must have the commonly granted `ALTER SYSTEM` privilege.
> - To alter a PDB, the current container must be the PDB and you must have the `ALTER SYSTEM` privilege, either granted commonly or granted locally in the PDB.

Which answers your question, yes, you need the correct privileges.